# Cast date and time to DateTime in hibernate query

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring boot with hibernate in my project. I would like to know if it is possible to cast date and time to datetime / timestamp in hibernate query.

What is the problem? I have table `Term`:

```
id_term|date      |time    |id_appointment|accepted|
-------|----------|--------|--------------|--------|
     45|2020-10-22|11:30:00|             6|       1|
   4247|2020-10-19|19:00:00|             4|       1|
  62648|2020-11-02|08:00:00|              |       0|
  62649|2020-11-02|08:30:00|              |       0|
```

As you can see, there is column `date` and `time`. I would like to get the next 25 free term from current "datetime" (Free term mean the `id_appointment` is NULL).
Currently I have query like this: `SELECT TOP 25 * FROM Term WHERE id_appointment IS NULL AND time > :currentTime AND date > :currentDate`. But it doesn't work correctly. Example if now is 2:15pm and tomorrow I have free term between 11am and 4pm, this query return me free terms only after 2:15pm. I'm looking for solution similiar to this: `SELECT TOP 25 * FROM Term WHERE id_appointment IS NULL AND CAST(date + time) > :currentDateTime`. The fields in `Term` class in Java are `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem. The correct answer is:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM term WHERE id_appointment IS NULL AND (CAST(date as datetime) + CAST(time as datetime)) > :currentDateTime ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC", nativeQuery=true)
List<Term> getNext20FreeTerms(@Param("currentDateTime") LocalDateTime currentDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is not fully working for me. I was getting the exception in Hibernate Native Query - "incompatible data types in combination in statement"
I had to include a space in between Date & Time. Well I am using SQL Server. Here is the updated query -

```
@Query(value = "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM term WHERE id_appointment IS NULL AND (CAST(date as datetime) + ' ' + CAST(time as datetime)) > :currentDateTime ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC", nativeQuery=true) 
List<Term> getNext20FreeTerms(@Param("currentDateTime") LocalDateTime currentDateTime);
```